# What is a python 2/3 compatible alternative to the unicode() function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, python-2.x, six

Is there an alternative to the python 2 `unicode()` function that can be used in code that will work with both python 2 and 3, and will definitely produce unicode output in python 2?

- the `unicode()` function does not exist in python 3
- `six.u(u'xyz')` raises an error in python 2

I am writing test code where I definitely want to produce unicode output so it will blow up in the tests if it is combined with a non-unicode string somewhere in the execution path - eg

```
'stuff %s' % u'unistuff'
```

For the general case I've seen it suggested to just use `str()`, but in python 2 that does NOT produce unicode.

I guess I could do:

```
if six.PY3:
    unicode = str
```

but surely there is some officially supported way.

(And it's quite hard to google for this as all the results are about unicode strings rather than the unicode function itself).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [the documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/six/#six.text_type) (which I'd recommend reading...) you want `six.text_type`:

> Type for representing (Unicode) textual data. This is `unicode()` in
>   Python 2 and `str` in Python 3.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I did read the documentation - I thought `text_type` was just a constant (it is in the "Constants" section) so it would only be used in `isinstance()`.  I hadn't realised it was also a function.